# How to change Content based on Menu Item click in AntD (React UI Library)

Tags: reactjs, menu, antd

I am following AntD Menu tutorial from [here](https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-custom-trigger) and it shows how to use this component. But I am failed to understand that how to change my Content when I click on different menu option. Tried searching a lot but did not find any useful help.

```
 import { Layout, Menu, Icon } from 'antd';

const { Header, Sider, Content } = Layout;

class SiderDemo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: false,
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Sider
          trigger={null}
          collapsible
          collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
        >
          <div className="logo" />
          <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
            <Menu.Item key="1">
              <Icon type="user" />
              <span>nav 1</span>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">
              <Icon type="video-camera" />
              <span>nav 2</span>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3">
              <Icon type="upload" />
              <span>nav 3</span>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
        <Layout>
          <Header style={{ background: '#fff', padding: 0 }}>
            <Icon
              className="trigger"
              type={this.state.collapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'}
              onClick={this.toggle}
            />
          </Header>
          <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px', padding: 24, background: '#fff', minHeight: 280 }}>
            Some Conent
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SiderDemo />, mountNode);
```

Can you pls help.

Comment: If you want to implement some kind of routing in your react application you might want to use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router).

Comment: Thanks @trixn but I found the solution. Will post below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just WRAP your Layout tag inside Router tag of `react-router-dom`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Layout, Menu, Icon } from 'antd';

import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Meseros from './containers/Meseros/Meseros';

const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;
const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;

class RouterApp extends Component {

    state = {
        collapsed: false,
    };

    onCollapse = (collapsed) => {
        this.setState({ collapsed });
    }
    toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>

                    <Sider
                        collapsible
                        collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
                        onCollapse={this.onCollapse}>
                        <div className="logo" />
                        <Menu theme="dark" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']} mode="inline">
                            <Menu.Item key="1">
                                <Icon type="pie-chart" />
                                <span>Deshboard</span>
                                <Link to="/" />
                            </Menu.Item>
                            <Menu.Item key="2">
                                <Icon type="desktop" />
                                <span>Meseros</span>
                                <Link to="/meseros" />
                            </Menu.Item>
                        </Menu>
                    </Sider>
                    <Layout>
                        <Header style={{ background: '#fff', padding: 0, paddingLeft: 16 }}>
                            <Icon
                                className="trigger"
                                type={this.state.collapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'}
                                style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                                onClick={this.toggle}
                            />
                        </Header>
                        <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px', padding: 24, background: '#fff', minHeight: 280 }}>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                            <Route path="/meseros" component={Meseros} />
                        </Content>

                    </Layout>

                </Layout>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}


export default RouterApp;
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to change the route every time you choose a menu item you can use the following approach

```
function MyComponent(){
 const [selectedMenuItem, setSelectedMenuItem]= useState('item1');

 const componentsSwtich = (key) => {
 switch (key) {
   case 'item1':
     return (<h1>item1</h1>);
   case 'item2':
     return (<h1>item2</h1>);
   case 'item3':
     return (<h3>item3/h3>);
   default:
     break;
  }
 };

return(
 <div>
  <Menu selectedKeys={selectedMenuItem} mode="horizontal" onClick={(e) => 
        setSelectedMenuItem(e.key)}>
    <Menu.Item key="item1">your first component here</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="item2">your second here</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="item3">your third here</Menu.Item>
   </Menu>
   <div>
     {componentsSwitch(selectedMenuItem)}
   </div>
 </div>)
```

Comment: @Jaikrat answer shows more relevant solution for given problem - you should replace the switch responses by fully routed content.

Answer (score 4):

You can bind `onClick` with your `MenuItem` and re render the component upon clicking any menuItem. And you can make you content in your `Constant.js` or initialize it in your component state.

Add onClick method

```
<Menu.Item 
 key="1"
 onClick={this.handleMenuClick}
 >
          <Icon type="user" />
          <span>nav 1</span>
</Menu.Item>
```

make a handle for `MenuItem` click:

```
handleMenuClick = event => {
 //you can get here event.target.value
 //filter the content 
 //setState the content your component will re render and content will be updated.

}
```

Comment: I got the solution of my question. Posted below.

Comment: Glad to hear this. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change the route, there is a working example here

https://codesandbox.io/embed/fervent-thunder-egyk1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Add Link component in Menu.Item and wrap with BrowserRouter from react-router-dom

```
<Menu.Item key="2">
  CI/CD Pipelines
  <Link to={`${match.url}/cicd`} />
</Menu.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the onClick prop for the Menu item as follow:
NB. I am using NextJs router to link the menus to their own corresponding page. In case you are using React, use Link from router-dom.

```
   <pre>
      <Menu
        onClick={({ keyPath }) => router.push(`/${keyPath}`)}
        mode="inline"
        defaultSelectedKeys={["dashboard"]}
        defaultOpenKeys={["company-info"]}
        items={navs}
        theme="dark"
     />
```

Comment: Thanks @Brhane for your reply. This question was asked long back and I had found the solution. But it will surely help others in case.